# Wordpress Ajax returns '0'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

There are quite a few similar problems I could find, but nothing helped, so have to post my own version of this question.

I have 2 php files:

- playing.php (contains the web form and sends the ajax call)
- plug_search.php (has the form processing code)

Before I started trying to use ajax, the form processing worked perfectly, the query worked as expected and the proper result was returned, based on the search parameters. Now, I want to use ajax, so the results are returned to the same page and it always returns '0'. I tried (seems like) everything I could, ruled out the most probable reasons (incorrect function/call name) - no luck. Feels like something very simple is missing, I suspect the problem is in the declaration of the function, but can't see what's wrong (it seems like the call never reaches processing function in plug_search.php). I stripped all the query code and just trying to return a simple string - still same '0'.
If you could help, I'd appreciate that a lot!

**playing.php**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      function search(){
         var plug=$("#autocomplete-dynamic").val();
         var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
         if(plug!==""){
            $("#result").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'ajax_return_search_results',
                    plug: 'country'
                },
                success:function(data){
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
         }
      }

      $("#button").click(function(){
         search();
      });

      $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            search();
         }
      });
   });
 </script>
```

**plug_search.php**

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_return_search_results', 'myajax_return_search_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_return_search_results', 'myajax_return_search_results' );

function myajax_return_search_results() {
   echo "Success";
   die();
}

?>
```

**plug_search.php** - Full version

```
function myajax_return_search_results() {

$value = $_GET['plug'];
$value2 = $_GET['country'];

$sql = "SELECT name, image_url, amazon_url, plug_type FROM adapters_list WHERE plug_type = '$value' AND country LIKE '%$value2%'" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

$result = $link->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
<div id="output-product" style="border: 1px solid #333; font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px;"><?php echo $row["name"] . "<br />";?>
<?php echo "</div>";

die();
```

}

Comment: Are you sure your `plug_search.php` file getting loaded in wordpress environment?

Comment: check this http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean by "getting loaded in wordpress environment", but I am working with a wordpress website and these two files are in a custom plugin folder I am building.

Comment: I mean if you add `die('getting loaded');` at the top of your 'plug_search.php' file what do you see?

Comment: Is there any error in console ? Check in network, what parameter is it taking ?

Comment: @MangeshParte adding `die('getting loaded');` didn't change anything, however if I try to access the plug_search.php file by direct url in the browser the console shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Did you add 'die('getting loaded');' this line at top of your file or you added that line in your 'myajax_return_search_results()' function? It should be at the top of your file like very 1st line of the file.

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner no errors when making the call, however something is wrong with plug_search.php itself, if I access it directly, the console shows error: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`. As for "check in network, what parameters is it taking?" - I don't see "Network" section in my Inspector (built-in Safari). Any other names it may go under?

Comment: Do one thing : add this code `error: function(errorThrown){  console.log(errorThrown);}` after success. Is it giving any error?

Comment: Also try by using `jQuery` instead of `$` for just for once. After doing it what is it giving ?

Comment: @MangeshParte at first, I added this on the second line after `<?php`. Now, I put it on the first line before `<?php` - still the same: getting '0' and the same error message in console when trying to go to plug_search.php file directly.

Comment: It means your file `plug_search.php` is not getting loaded in wordpress environment. If you paste `myajax_return_search_results()` in `functions.php` you will get your problem fixed (for time being).

Comment: @Rohil_PHPBeginner added `error:...` right after `...alert(data);},` - nothing changed. Changed `$.ajax` to `jQuery.ajax` - still the same. And no errors in console.

Comment: @MangeshParte added to `functions.php`. Now, the playing.php (with the web-form and ajax call) is not loading at all - just blank screen. Console is clean.

Comment: It's just coz you forgot to delete `myajax_return_search_results()` function from `plug_search.php`.

Comment: @MangeshParte your solution from below worked! thank you! But it seems to be exactly the same code that I have in plug_search.php. Why it doesn't work from there?

Answer (score 3):

Add this code in your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ajax_return_search_results', 'myajax_return_search_results' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_return_search_results', 'myajax_return_search_results' );

function myajax_return_search_results() {
   echo "Success";
   die();
}
```

Comment: Ok, this thing worked and returns "Success" now. But it seems to be exactly the same code that I have in plug_search.php. Why it doesn't work from there?

Comment: Coz your `plug_search.php` file is not getting loaded. Paste your plugins main file content here and I will tell you how you can get it worked from plugin itself.

Comment: Ok, added the initial processing code from plug_search.php to functions.php. Result: page not loading at all, blank screen, console empty. If I comment out that initial code with the query, the pages shows up, so something is wrong with that function. I'll put it up in the post itself, so it is easier to read.

Comment: Friend you are missing `;` in query, $sql = "SELECT name, image_url, amazon_url, plug_type FROM adapters_list WHERE plug_type = '$value' AND country LIKE '%$value2%'"`;` or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link)); and remove this part `or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: So only this much part remains in query: `$sql = "SELECT name, image_url, amazon_url, plug_type FROM adapters_list WHERE plug_type = '$value' AND country LIKE '%$value2%'";`

Comment: Updated - still blank screen

Answer (score 0):

data is returning an error code because you are using .success instead of .done

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    action: 'ajax_return_search_results',
                    plug: 'country'
                }

            }).done(function(data){
                   alert(data);
                });
```

Comment: Updated to .done - now, it doesn't even show alert window (which is popping up with .success)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing datatype in ajax
Try adding it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      function search(){
         var plug=$("#autocomplete-dynamic").val();
         var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>";
         if(plug!==""){
            $("#result").html();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: 'html',
                data: {
                    action: 'ajax_return_search_results',
                    plug: 'country'
                },
                success:function(data){
                   alert(data);
                }
            });
         }
      }

      $("#button").click(function(){
         search();
      });

      $('#search').keyup(function(e) {
         if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            search();
         }
      });
   });
```

Comment: Added `dataType: 'html',` - still returns '0'